# D3.js resize and drag

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm drawing a tree with D3. When the page is resized I want to move the tree to a specific position (basically on the space left for the svg so the tree stay visible).
I use this code

```
function resize() {
  svg
    .attr("width", getWidth())
    .attr("height", getHeight());
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + (window.innerWidth / 3) + "," + ((window.innerHeight / 3)) + ")" + " scale(1)");
  var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom();
  zoom.translate([window.innerWidth / 3, window.innerHeight / 3]);
}
d3.select(window).on('resize', resize);
```

This works fine, but when I start clicking to drag the graph, it's moved to the original position as starting drag point.
This is the drag function:

```
function redraw() {
  if (!d3.event.sourceEvent) return;
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    svg.attr("transform",
      "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" +
      " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
        .attr("id", "graph")
        .attr("width", getWidth())
        .attr("height", getHeight())
        .call(zm = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw)).on("dblclick.zoom", null)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + initialWidth + "," + initialHeight + ")");
```

Any hint on how to solve this?

Comment: make `var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw);` a global variable and use it in both places `....call(zoom)` and in resize function

Comment: Tested the solution. It works great! Please add it as an answer for the future reades

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make zoom a global variable like this:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw);
```

and use it in resize and zoom for svg as shown below.

**Change 1:**

```
var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
        .attr("id", "graph")
        .attr("width", getWidth())
        .attr("height", getHeight())
        .call(zoom).on("dblclick.zoom", null)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + initialWidth + "," + initialHeight + ")")
```

**Change 2:**

```
function resize() {
            svg
                .attr("width", getWidth())
                .attr("height", getHeight());
            svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + (window.innerWidth / 3) + "," + ((window.innerHeight / 3)) + ")" + " scale(1)");
            zoom.translate([window.innerWidth / 3, window.innerHeight / 3]);
        }
```